# Sort by two columns

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of dictionaries with columns A and B I want to sort by A ascending and B descending.

I can do this job using Pandas.

```
df.sort_values(["A", "B"], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```

However, in some cases, I want to prioritize column B because this column represents the amount, and column A the time it takes. In other words, I want to maximize the amount in a max period; with my naive approach, I am only prioritizing the minimum time followed by the amount. I want both.

Is there some sorting algorithm that solves this?

Input

list = [
{"A": 10, "B": 200},
{"A": 70, "B": 1000},
{"A": 10, "B": 300},
{"A": 10, "B": 100},
]

Output in max of 80ms

output = [
{"A": 10, "B": 300},
{"A": 70, "B": 1000},
]

In a max of 80ms, the amount is 1300

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output. You have 2 dimensions here... imagine a 2D plane with X and Y axes with scattered points in all directions. How would you want to sort them?

Comment: Could it be you want the max amount in min period, maybe to order by (amount / time) ?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea, the max amount in a period of time

Comment: @trincot I have provide a sample

Comment: Oh OK, that is aggregation (grouping), not sorting.

Comment: Interesting, searching for aggregation could help me. Thanks @trincot

Comment: Also, your question will get the attention of the right people if you tag it with `python` and `pandas`.

Comment: I'm closing the question as it was not a all about sorting but rather about solving a knapsack problem